# How to change size of React component?

Tags: css, reactjs

Here is the component I use - https://github.com/effectussoftware/react-custom-roulette/.
[I see](https://github.com/effectussoftware/react-custom-roulette/blob/master/src/components/Wheel/styles.js) that it limits the roulette size -

```
export const RouletteContainer = styled.div`
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 445px;
  height: 80vw;
  max-height: 445px;
`;
```

I tried to overwrite it at App.css -

```
div .wheel { // also tried .RouletteContainer, .wheel
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 700px;
}
```

but it doesn't help.

The following I see in the console -
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
.wheel > div:first-child {
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 700px;
}
```

from what I can tell, the style is applied to the `div` that is the child of `.wheel` ? If that targets the correct node but specificity is not high enough to override their styles, you may have to mark them as `!important`

`:first-child` is also just me guessing that the node will always be the first div, you can update this based on what their DOM node structure will actually be